# Django postgres unique constraint name generation

Tags: django, postgresql

When adding a new unique constraint on a django model, this will automatically create a name for this constraint in postgres.
Does Postgres generate this name or is it Django? Is it deterministic?

for example I use this model

```py
class MyModel(Model):
  field1 = TextField()
  field2 = IntegerField()

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ("field1", "field2")
```

I got the name of the constraint with

```sql
select constraint_name
from information_schema.constraint_column_usage
where table_name = 'myapp_mytable'
```

I get a name like `field1_field2_d04755de_uniq`

Comment: Django will create this name. But using `unique_together` is deprecated. You should work with a `UniqueConstraint` where you can also manually specify the name of the constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django will determine this name. Indeed, the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L1536-L1537) shows that it determines the name with:

> ```
> if name is None:
>     name = IndexName(table, columns, "_uniq", create_unique_name)
> ```

The [**`IndexName`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/db/backends/ddl_references.py#L103-L112) will call `create_unique_name` with the `table`, `columns` and `suffix`:

> ```
> class IndexName(TableColumns):
>     
>     def __init__(self, table, columns, suffix, create_index_name):
>         # …
>         pass
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.create_index_name(self.table, self.columns, self.suffix)
> ```

and the `create_unique_name` will return a quoted version of `_create_index_name`, which will [make a *digest* of the `table_name` and `column_names` <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L1221-L1251):

> ```
> def _create_index_name(self, table_name, column_names, suffix=""):
>     # …
>     _, table_name = split_identifier(table_name)
>     hash_suffix_part = "%s%s" % (
>         names_digest(table_name, *column_names, length=8),
>         suffix,
>     )
>     # …
> ```

But using `unique_together` is likely to become deprecated. Indeed, the [documentation on **`unique_together`** says <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

> **Use [`UniqueConstraint` <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint)
> with the
> [`constraints` <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint)
> option instead.**
>
> [`UniqueConstraint` <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint)
> provides more functionality than `unique_together`. `unique_together`
> may be deprecated in the future.

You can define this `UniqueConstraint` where you can also manually specify the name of the constraint:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('field1', 'field2'), name='some_constraint_name')
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @willem-van-onsem, using [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/) allows to set the constraint name (which is pretty deterministic)